# How do you Make a URL string in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make a url string to one of my mapped routes in the CS file. I can do it in the aspx file via the html helpers. How do you make a url in the CS file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [UrlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper in your C# method, and use that to call your Html Helper methods.

Comment: would you happen to have an example?

Comment: Not without more information about what you're trying to do. If you just want to build an Url in a controller method, korchev's suggestion of using the UrlHelper class would be easier, as it doesn't require a ViewContext and ViewContainer as arguments to the constructor.

Comment: I can use the urlhelper but how do you get the requestcontext value? I am not using this method in a controller. It is in my model.

Comment: I know how to get it in the controller, but not in the model. In the controller, it is ControllerContext.RequestContext.  Which makes sense, because a RequestContext doesn't actually exist until a request has occurred.